# TYPO3 10.4 / FLUIDTEMPLATE / renderObj / image

Tags: image, typo3, content-management-system, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I've got a simple template which displays the full content from "content_icon" for a "page" - so far everything fine.

Now I want to add only the image(s) from the "content_icon" - no way.

This ist the (ext+)template:

```
<f:section name="main">
  <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{content_icon}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
  <p>-----------------------------</p>
  <p>
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="SliderElement.10.variables.icon"/>
  </p>
  <p>{icon}</p>
</f:section>
```

I've tried this (and many more)
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html#usage-with-references but -> no output at all.

I figured out, that if I add the following assignment anything seems to be read .... I get an output - but without images ....

```
page_id < styles.content.get
```

Struggeling now for 3 days with TYPO3 10.4 extension (template).
Didn't see any light.

```
  SliderElement = PAGE
  SliderElement.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  SliderElement.10 {
   format = html
   file = fileadmin/site_elements/Templates/SliderElement.html
   partialRootPath = fileadmin/site_elements/Partials/
   layoutRootPath = fileadmin/site_elements/Layouts/
   variables {
     page_id = FILE
     page_id < styles.content.get
     page_id.select.where = "tt_content"."colPos" = 20
     page_id {
       stdWrap.wrap = <div class="pic">|</div>
       references {
         uid.data = uid
         #fieldName = image // try
         #fieldName = media // try
         fieldName = assets
       }
       renderObj = IMAGE
       renderObj {
         file {
           import.data = file:current:uid
           treatIdAsReference = 1
         }
         altText.data = file:current:alternative
         stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
       }
     }

      content_icon < styles.content.get
      content_icon.select.where = "tt_content"."colPos" = 20
   }
}
```

Any help or idea would be nice...

Comment: Can you please specify where the information for the source of the picture comes from?

Comment: I've tried different content elements like "Text & Images", "Images only" and "Text & Media", but no difference - no output

Comment: The content element is on the same page? (TYPO3 adds automatically a `pid=<currentPid>` to the `where`-clause, if `pid` is not already set)

Comment: Yes, it is on the same page.